# Resteasy Path with expressions including spaces

Tags: regex, path, expression, resteasy

I am reading the book "RESTful Java"; now I am working with the examples from chapter 4.
I would like to change the expressions to accept names with spaces. I've changed the expressions to "[a-zA-Z ]+" but it didn't work. Is there a way to make this work?

Many thanks

```
   @GET
   @Path("{first : [a-zA-Z]+}-{last:[a-zA-Z]+}")
   @Produces("application/xml")
   public StreamingOutput getCustomerFirstLast(@PathParam("first") String first,
                                               @PathParam("last") String last)
   {
    System.out.println(String.format("Parameters. First=%s; Last=%s", first, last));
      Customer found = null;
      for (Customer cust : customerDB.values())
      {
         if (cust.getFirstName().equals(first) && cust.getLastName().equals(last))
         {
            found = cust;
            break;
         }
      }
      if (found == null)
      {
         throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
      }
      final Customer customer = found;
      return new StreamingOutput()
      {
         public void write(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException
         {
            outputCustomer(outputStream, customer);
         }
      };
   }
```

Edit: I was not clear.

When I try the URL: /customers/Sylvie-Van%20der%20Vaart I am getting the following error:

> HTTP ERROR 404
>
> Problem accessing
>   /customers/Sylvie-Van%20der%20Vaart.
>   Reason:
>
> ```
> Could not find resource for relative :
> ```
>
> /customers/Sylvie-Van%20der%20Vaart of
>   full path:
>   http://localhost:9095/customers/Sylvie-Van%20der%20Vaart

I tried simply to add to the regular expression one space:@Path("{first : [a-zA-Z ]+}-{last:[a-zA-Z ]+}").

Comment: "didn't work". How cryptic. Try escaped spaces, `%20`. `+` is also possible, but it is grossly outdated. Also, are you sure you didn't mean `[+ ]`?

Comment: "Didn't work", was not really clear. I am sorry. When I try the URL http://localhost:9095/customers/Sylvie-Van%20der%20Vaart I get:Problem accessing /customers/Sylvie-Van%20der%20Vaart. Reason:

    Could not find resource for relative : /customers/Sylvie-Van%20der%20Vaart of full path: http://localhost:9095/customers/Sylvie-Van%20der%20Vaart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[a-zA-Z]+([\\s]?[a-zA-Z]+)*
```

[a-zA-Z]+   is for the first name

([\s]?[a-zA-Z]+)* is for the optional more names

I think above regular expression will handle the cases you are asking.